# SOQL Query for getting the Application name of a Particular Tab

Tags: salesforce, apex, soql

I would like to get the Application name of a specific sObject. For example: I have a custom object called Candidate__c. How to get the Application name of Candidate__c programmatically? 
I am open to any approach like using Schema Namespace as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering my question. I used Schema.describeTabs() and It works perfectly, but the [Doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/.../apex_methods_system...) says `the DescribeTabs method returns the minimum required metadata that can be used to render apps ...`
Basically, The `All Tabs` are not included in the list of described tabs. The results are dependent upon the apps that are available to the running user.

```
// Get tab set describes for each app
List<Schema.DescribeTabSetResult> allApps = Schema.describeTabs();

// Iterate through each tab set describe for each app
for (Schema.DescribeTabSetResult oneApp : allApps) {
    System.debug('The tabs/objects associated with the' + oneApp.getLabel() + ' app are:');
    List<Schema.DescribeTabResult> appTabs = oneApp.getTabs();
    for (Integer i = 0; i < appTabs.size(); i++) {
        System.debug((i + 1) + '. Tab Name: ' + appTabs[i].getLabel());
    }
}
```